# Detect apparent prevalence

Tags: estimation, prevalence

I have farms in my dataset and from each farm, I have a few animals (varies for each farm) to test for a disease. I want to know, if I tested these animals, what apparent prevalence will I be able to detect in each herd. I want to estimate this for each herd.

There is a formula for estimating the sample size for a given prevalence; but how could one estimate the prevalence, if the sample size is known?